# How to read class Properties without instantiation?

Tags: c#, .net

How can i read all class Properties, without having an instantiated object of this Class nor hard-coding the name of the class itself?
The name of the class is stored in a string-variable.

```
string className = "myNamespace.myClass";
PropertyInfo[] myPropertyInfo;
try
{
    myPropertyInfo = Type.GetType(className).GetProperties();
} catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

always returns a

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I'd like avoiding a solution like

```
switch(className) {
   case "myNamespace.myClass":
      myNamespace.myClass obj = new();
      break;
   case "myNamespace.anotherClass":
      myNamespace.anotherClass obj = new();
      break;
   case "anotherNamespace.myClass":
      anotherNamespace.myClass obj = new();
      break;
}
myPropertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `Type.ToString()` just returns the types (short) name without qualifiers. So in your case just `"MyModel"` instead of `"MyNamespace.MyModel, MyAssembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"`. However `Type.GetType()` needs an assembly-qualfied name. Otherwise it just returns null because the type wans't found. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=net-7.0#system-type-gettype(system-string)) for the string-parameter for `Type.GetType`:

> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See
> AssemblyQualifiedName. If the type is in the currently executing
> assembly or in mscorlib.dll/System.Private.CoreLib.dll, it is
> sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.

Instead of using `mod.GetType.ToString()` you should use `mod.GetType.AssemblyQualifiedName`.

When on the other hand you already have a concrete instance of your model-class and call `GetType` on that, you never get `null`, as every object has a type.

Comment: Hi, thank you. And what if the Object 'mod' isn't available, but a variable containing namespace and class Name, e.g. String classname = "my.namespace.myModel"; I guess  my first example above is confusing.

Comment: Hi @MakePeaceGreatAgain, i just rewrote my question. Maybe this helps to precise the problem

Comment: @Besi you need to provide an assembly-qualified named as mentioned in the docs for `Type.GetType`. This is a string containing the namespace, the type-name, the assembly, it's version and it's culture